# Sind "Nutzerverhalten" und "Konsumentenverhalten" gleichbedeutend?

Tags: difference, noun, meaning

Sind die Begriffe 'Nutzerverhalten' und 'Konsumentenverhalten', speziell bezogen auf den Kontext des Web, gleichbedeutend?

Der Begriff "Konsument" wird – soweit ich gelesen habe – mittlerweile etwas weiter gefasst und bezeichnet nicht mehr nur den Verbrauch von Gütern, sondern auch die Inanspruchnahme von Ressourcen.

Comment: Was für einen Unterschied erwartest Du denn? Was läßt Dich zweifeln? Ich verstehe nicht, was gefragt ist.

Comment: Die Aussicht, eine gute Antwort zu bekommen, verbessert sich, wenn Fragesteller erklären, was sie bereits von sich aus getan haben. In diesem Fall z.B., wie unterscheiden sich die Suchmaschinentreffer für Nutzerverhalten und Konsumentenverhalten voneinander, welche Webseiten (Wörterbücher, Online-Zeitungen, Bücher auf Gutenberg.org oder Google Books, usw.) wurden konsultiert, welche Unklarheiten bestehen dann noch. Ansonsten werden Fragen bald geschlossen, was nicht unfreundlich gemeint ist: eine geschlossene Frage kann verbessert werden. Siehe auch die FAQ rechts oben auf der Menüleiste.

Comment: Dieser Unterschied kann auf jenen zwischen "Konsument" und "Nutzer" zurückgeführt werden.

Answer (score 1):

Die Bedeutung beider Wörter sind sehr ähnlich, haben aber verschiedene Konnotationen. "Konsumentenverhalten" deutet meiner Meinung nach darauf hin, dass am Ende irgendwas bezahlt werden muss. Zum Beispiel könnte man vom "Konsumentenverhalten auf der Amazon-Webseite" sprechen, aber nur vom "Nutzerverhalten auf Wikipedia", sonst klingt es in meinen Ohren eher komisch.

Comment: Konsum ist nicht an Tausch und Bezahlung gebunden. Kinder konsumieren Nahrung die sie nicht bezahlen und man kann auch wild wachsende Früchte in der Natur konsumieren. Im engeren Sinne bedeutet Konsum Verzehr, was bei Internetinhalten üblicherweise nicht passiert - sie sind nach der Aufnahme immer noch da. Konsum wird aber weitgehend im übertragenen Sinne gebraucht, etwa das Konsumieren von Büchern, Filmen oder Musikaufnahmen.

Answer (score 0):

Nein, diese Wörter transportieren nach wie vor grundverschiedene Bedeutungen und Assoziationen. Der Unterschied mag allenfalls bei bestimmten Thematiken bzw. aus gewissen Betrachtungswinkeln (z.B. Ökonomie) relativ unbedeutend sein.

Answer (score 0):

Als Leser eines Blogs bist Du ein Konsument und ein Nutzer, als Blogbetreiber bist Du ein Nutzer, aber bezogen auf die Inhalte nicht Konsument, sondern Produzent.

Answer (score 0):

Konsumentenverhalten ist das Verhalten eines Konsumenten. Nutzverhalten das eines Nutzers. Es sollte also genügen, Konsument und Nutzer zu unterscheiden um dann auch die Verhaltensunterschiede zu verstehen.

Es gibt einen sehr wichtigen Unterschied in Hinblick auf die gesetzliche Gewährleistung im Fall eines Mangels oder Schadens:

### Konsument

Dem Gesetz nach ist ein Konsument jemand, der eine Ware oder Dienstleistung als Privatperson verwendet, verbraucht, in Anspruch nimmt, oder auf andere Weise konsumiert. Der ausschlaggebende Aspekt ist die **Privat**-Person. Ein Unternehmer, der eine Ware oder Dienstleistung nutzt um damit sein Geschäft zu führen, ist per Definition kein Konsument. Wenn derselbe Unternehmer aber eine Dienstleistung als Privatmensch in Anspruch nimmt, ist er dennoch Konsument.

**Beispiel:**
Ich bin Unternehmer (Softwareentwickler, EPU = Einzel-Personen-Unternehmen). Wenn ich in einem Elektronik-Supermarkt einen Drucker für mein Büro kaufe, ihn in meiner Buchhaltung als Teil des Betriebsvermögens aufnehme, und für die Ausübung meines Berufes verwende, dann habe ich diesen Drucker nicht als Konsument gekauft. Ich habe daher kein Recht, ihn kostenlos umtauschen oder reparieren zu lassen, wenn ich zwei Monate nach dem Kauf bemerke, dass er von Anfang an einen Mangel hatte, der aber eben erst jetzt offenkundig wurde.
Als Konsument hätte ich zwei Jahre lang das Recht auf Behebung eines Mangels, und innerhalb der ersten sechs Monate müsste ich nicht einmal nachweisen, dass der Mangel schon beim Kauf bestanden hat.

Wenn ich aber, obwohl ich Unternehmer bin, einen Apfel kaufe, hineinbeiße und feststelle, dass er innen faulig ist, kann ich den Apfel selbstverständlich umtauschen, denn ich habe den Apfel als Privatperson, also als Konsument gekauft, und habe in diesem Fall auch alle Rechte eines Konsumenten, obwohl ich Inhaber einer Firma bin. Dieses Recht auf Umtausch habe ich auch dann, wenn man dem Apfel das faulige Innenleben im Geschäft nicht ansehen konnte, und dem Apfelverkäufer daher gar keine Schuld oder böse Absicht unterstellt werden kann.

### Nutzer

Ein Nutzer ist jemand, der eine Sache oder Dienstleistung nutzt. Das kann auch ein Frächter sein, der einen LKW nutzt, um Waren seiner Auftraggeber von A nach B zu transportieren. Der Frächter ist Nutzer des LWKs, aber er hat in Bezug auf den LWK keine Rechte als Konsument. Wenn der Motor des LWKs zwei Wochen nach dem Kauf den Geist aufgibt, muss der Frächter ihn auf eigene Kosten reparieren.

Ausnahmen gibt es: Wenn der Hersteller den Schaden absichtlich oder groß fahrlässig verursacht hat, muss er auch einem Geschäftskunden gegenüber haften. Im Fall von leichter Fahrlässigkeit oder Zufall jedoch nicht.